# Encode amr with ffmpeg (libavcodec)

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, amr

I would like to encode a simple pcm to amr using libavcodec.

To begin with, I compiled ffmpeg and run the `encode_audio` example and it worked fine for the default Mp2 codec.

Then modified the [encode_audio](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_audio.c) example and replace `AV_CODEC_ID_MP2` with `AV_CODEC_ID_AMR_NB` and changed `bit_rate`, `sample_rate`, and `channel_layout` to `12200`, `8000`, and `AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO` respectively. Now, I am getting `invalid fastbin entry (free)` error.

The compiled `ffmpeg` cli binary worked as expected and encode audio files to `amr` successfully, so the issue is not in compilation or the linking step.

Any help would be much appreciated

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is not specifically for `amr` and the `encode_audio` example would fail for all codecs if `AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO` is selected for the channel layout. To get the demo to work, you need to also change the signal generator code block, in which having two channels of audio if assumed and hard-corded. Thanks [@ronald-s-bultje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4726410/ronald-s-bultje) for helping me here.

Comment: Could you post the output you see when running `ffprobe` on the `amr` file generated using the `ffmpeg` CLI binary?

Comment: Input #0, amr, from 'audio.amr':
  Duration: 00:00:45.52, bitrate: 12 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: amr_nb (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, flt

Comment: Did you set `channels` to `1` (in addition to setting `channel_layout` to `AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO`)?

Comment: Yes, I did; does it work for you with these changes?

Comment: Actually I realized even for other codecs, `FLAC` for instance, once I change the `channel_layout` to `AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO`, the demo fails again.